# Camera application giving exception at the start in android

Tags: android, camera

To get started with camera application in android I have written some code to perform the following steps:
1.Preview 
2.Capture Image 
3.Save Image
4.Preview Again

Here is the whole code to perform the above steps:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,Camera.AutoFocusCallback,Camera.PictureCallback
{
String SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "tmpPhoto.jpg";
private Camera mCamera;
boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
ImageButton takePictureButton;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    takePictureButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.capture_img);
    takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, CameraActivity.this);
        }
    });
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR)));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureFromCameraIntent, 1);

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Picture taken from camera
    if(requestCode == 1)
    {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            File f = new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR);
            try{
                Uri capturedImage = 
                    Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), f.getAbsolutePath(), 
                            null, null));

                Log.i("camera", "Selected image: "+capturedImage.toString());
                f.delete();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("camera", "Result Code was: " + resultCode);
    }
}
@Override
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mPreviewRunning)
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    p.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    p.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);

    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }catch(IOException ie)
    {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera = Camera.open();

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();

}
 }
```

When I run the above code, at the start of the app itself it is giving me a message that it has stopped unexpectedly.
Have I done any mistake here? I want to know because I am new for Camera. Please help me!!!
Thank You

Comment: It's hard for people to help you if you don't give them much information. What problem are you having? What doesn't work? Does the application Force Close? If so what's the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you include Camera permission in Manifest?

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"

Comment: And what exception do you have? You can watch it in logcat.

Comment: @Sohaib:-Check your xml file.spelling or any inconsistency

Comment: @Rasel: I have checked it. It is proper.

Comment: @Maxim: I am running it on the android phone

Comment: If you connect phone to you PC and run logcat you can watch it anyway. Otherwise you will never know exact reason of any exception you'll catch

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(  329): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11
E/AndroidRuntime(  329): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec /AndroidRuntime(  329):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChoose
r.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(  329):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(
GLSurfaceView.java:916)
E/AndroidRuntime(  329):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guarded
Run(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
E/AndroidRuntime(  329):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLS
urfaceView.java:1116)

Comment: Have you set preview size or other parameters on Camera.Parameters instance?